# Connected battery the wrong way, what should I do?

Tags: battery, repair

I connected the battery the wrong way on an old Toyota MR2 turbo.

The interior lights stopped working, otherwise the car starts and seem to work, exterior lights work.

How do I repair the interior lights?

Should I replace/repair anything else I'm not aware of?

Comment: Check the fuse for those lights.

Comment: make sure you check all of the fuses that relate to the interior lights.

Answer (score 1):

it's "possible" you damaged the body computer if your car has one but in general car lightbulbs don't give a crap which way the voltage flows through them.  It may just be a coincidence and you popped a fuse, but you could have fried a capacitor if your lights have dimming cycles when you open and shut the door.